# use title attribute for caption with fancybox4

Tags: javascript, fancybox, caption

Using fancybox4 would it be possible to use the title attribute as a caption?

```
<a href="aaaa.jpg" title="Image 1" rel="lightbox[aaa]"><img src="aaa.jpg" alt="alt image 1"></a>

Fancybox.bind("a[rel^=lightbox]", {
  groupAll : true,
  caption: ........
});
```

Example here: https://jsfiddle.net/eh2q3zr0/

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by changing the caption option:

```
Fancybox.bind("a[rel^=lightbox]", {
  groupAll : true,
  caption: function(fancybox, carousel, slide) {
    return slide.$trigger.title || '';
  }
});
```

Comment: good solution)))